# regex expression to get last 6 characters preceding file extension

Tags: c#, regex

I need a C# regex to extract the last 6 letters of a string and add a forward slash in the middle of them. For example:

```
xx_xxxx_xxxABCXYZ.Something.csv
```

I need `ABC/XYZ`

The 3 letter components could be anything and the amount of x's in front varies. However, the 6 letters I need are always immediately preceding the first period.

I don't have the option of additional code because I need to input the Pattern and Replacement into a GUI.

Much appreciated.

Comment: `(\w{3})(\w{3})(?=\.)` and replace with `$1/$2` (only the first match!), but I don't know the C# code off the top of my head.

Comment: This is very close except it does the reverse. The pattern gives me "xx_xxx_xx.Something.csv" and adding the replacement results in "xx_xxx_xxABC/XYZ.Something.csv". I need to input this regex into a GUI so I dont have the option of additional C# code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `^.*?(\w{3})(\w{3})(?=\.).*$` (and then do the mentioned replacement)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Post it as answer and I'll mark as answer

Comment: Regex is slower than just doing it manually by getting the correct location of the string to put the slash in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
^.*?(\w{3})(\w{3})\..*$
```

Replace with:

```
$1/$2
```

The pattern matches the whole string so everything gets removed in the end, but it captures the two string of 3 characters each in capturing groups. These are then accessed and put back in place with `$1` and `$2`. The pattern is also followed by `\.`, so there has to be a dot following the six characters. The `?` after the `.*` makes sure that you find the first possible occurrence (instead of `ething`).

Note that this allows for digits, letters and underscores to make up the six characters. If you only want letters, use `[a-zA-Z]` or `[A-Z]` for upper-case only.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for additional explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and then [string.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to add the slash

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I don't have the option of additional code because I need to input the Pattern and Replacement into a GUI.

Comment: `.Something` isn't part of the extension.  What you're doing is removing `.csv`

Comment: @Vazgen Ok I'll leave my post any way.